# Lists of lists in C# Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm writing a Xamarin.Forms application in C# using Newtonsoft JSON.

My REST service is returning an array of categories, and each category has an array of items (in JSON)

My question is: what do I deserialize this into?

What I'd like is to have a list where a category is defined to be something like:

```
public class Category {
  private string categoryName;
  private List<Item> items;
}
```

and have the json just deserialize properly.  Can that be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add sample JSON? It can probably done with the proper attributes.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I learned C# from one of your books years ago, it was an excellent book, thanks !

Comment: You could use [this Tool](http://json2csharp.com/) to see what class you need to deserialize into.

Comment: I've come to believe C# can't do that.  In any case, the easier way was to flatten the list and then to use grouping in my listview.

Answer (score 0):

just use `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(JSONString)`

if the JSON string matches the class you will get the result you want